# Upper Bound on ${n \choose r} $

Tags: combinations, factorial

$$ {n \choose r} \leq \frac{n^n}{r^r ~\cdot~ (n-r)^{(n-r)}} $$

I have a feeling that the above holds but I am not so sure how I go about proving it. Any insights?

Comment: You need to be careful about where this is defined. What if $n=r$

Comment: @StellaBiderman in the field of combinatorics, generally $0^0$ takes the value of $1$.  There is no issue here then as both the LHS and the RHS take the value of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this a bit more and seems like it can be proved using Stirling's approximation:
$$ n! \leq 2\sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
$$ {n \choose r} = \frac{n!}{r! \cdot (n-r)!} \leq \frac{n^n}{r^r \cdot (n-r)^{(n-r)}} \sqrt{\frac{n}{r \cdot (n-r)}}$$
$$ \leq \frac{n^n}{r^r \cdot (n-r)^{(n-r)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

One technique for proving statements like this is to prove that the error in the approximation is a multiplicative factor >1. In this case, in the numerator you increase each of the numbers in the set $[n]$ to $n$. In the denominator, you are also increasing $n$-many terms so we can pair them up. Pairing them up cleverly lets you arrive at the conclusion that this holds for $n>4$, and then you can check small cases by hand.

Comment: Can you be more precise. As in, how exactly will you pair them up?